# How can I fetch the HTML contents of one single TYPO3 page into another CMS?

Tags: php, html, xml-rpc, typo3, habari

We need to display the content of one single TYPO3 page in Habari.

It would suffice to retrieve the HTML, as styling (CSS) is done separatly.
However, we *only* want the HTML of the **content** elements - not the whole, fully rendered page.

- How could we achieve that?
- Does TYPO3 (or one of its plugins) provide a facility for that?

Comment: I have accepted the web-service variant Fedir suggested, as it appears to be the 'cleanest' variant. However a combination of Bear's answer (for the TYPO3 side) and lildude's (for the Habari side) would be a reasonable solution as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW, You could use typo3_webservice fro that. It uses XMLRPC protocol, and quite easy to implement with PHP.

http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/typo3_webservice/current/

Answer (score 2):

This can be done via a custom Typoscript template-record in the Typo3 backend that just outputs the content without any further HTML  and or  tags.

Putting something like this in the 'setup':

```
page = PAGE
page.config.disableAllHeaderCode = 1
page.10 < styles.content.get
```

Then make sure in the template-record it say's that it's a root-template, and that it clears constants and setup before this template. And put this record on the top most page (aka root).

Also make sure that you included the static template of `CSS Styled Content`. This can be done when editing the template-record inside Typo3.

Comment: Probably, You could use it together with GET/POST condition, so You could have an additional version of Your page without to loose original presentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in Habari using something like this:

```
$url = "http://your-typo3-url/";
$output = RemoteRequest::get_contents( $url );
```

$output will then be the HTML contents of the page.  You can then use a combination of `strpos()` and `substr()` to pull the relevant HTML content you want, eg just the `<body>`

You can do this in one of your theme template files, the theme's `theme.php` file itself or even within a plugin.

You can then use Habari's native caching to cache the content too so you don't have to retrieve the Typo3 page with every page view.